# how to align a slider (input type range) with the text to its right for its value?

Tags: css, html

What would be the simplest way to align a slider with the value of the slider which is on its right? Without using external library. Just using HTML5? Do I need to use CSS for this? How?

```js
updateTextInput('0');

function updateTextInput(val) {
  document.getElementById('amount').value = val; //update current slider value
  // do other action here
}
```

```html
<input type="range" id="rangeInput" name="rangeInput" min="0" max="100" value="0" step="1" oninput="updateTextInput(this.value);">
<output name="amount" id="amount" for="rangeInput">0</output>
```

When running the above, the output (on Chrome on windows looks like)

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You can see the number is not aligned horizontally well with the slider. It should be a little higher.

I know there are many ways to align things in CSS and HTML. But I am not sure with a slider like this what would be the best way to go about it.

ps. sorry do not know how to make a "JSFiddle" yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just add below two css properties for both the elements.

```css
input,output{display: inline-block;
vertical-align: middle;}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<body>

    <input type="range" id="rangeInput" name="rangeInput"
           min="0" max="100" value="0" step="1" data-show-value="true"
           oninput="updateTextInput(this.value);">

    <output name="amount" id="amount" for="rangeInput">0</output>
    <BR>
<script>
    updateTextInput('0');

    function updateTextInput(val)
    {
      document.getElementById('amount').value=val; //update current slider value
      // do other action here
    }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `input` and `output` both are `inline` elements which are aligned to `baseline` by default...

...so set `vertical-align:middle` to both to align them vertically `center`

***Stack Snippet***

```js
updateTextInput('0');

function updateTextInput(val) {
  document.getElementById('amount').value = val; //update current slider value
  // do other action here
}
```

```css
input,
output {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<input type="range" id="rangeInput" name="rangeInput" min="0" max="100" value="0" step="1" oninput="updateTextInput(this.value);">
<output name="amount" id="amount" for="rangeInput">0</output>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a parent div for input rang and output the and  this parent div  element should be position: relative and  output element should be position: absolute with these properties position: absolute;  right: 0px;  top: 5px; you can set top position according you what your need. Your input rang width should be 90% or what do you want according to your query.